# pam_mount error "crypt_activate_by_passphrase: Operation not permitted"

Tags: opensuse, luks, pam-mount

I'm trying to set up encrypted home directories on OpenSuSE.

Everything works fine for direct login, but I want the home directories to get mounted via `ssh` as well. When I try to `ssh` to the machine, and provide a password, the following shows up in `/var/log/messages`.

```
Sep 20 16:03:16 linux-bd9o sshd[11921]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for test from ::1 port 37227 ssh2
Sep 20 16:03:16 linux-bd9o sshd[11921]: pam_mount(pam_mount.c:172): conv->conv(...): Conversation error
Sep 20 16:03:16 linux-bd9o sshd[11921]: pam_mount(pam_mount.c:476): warning: could not obtain password interactively either
Sep 20 16:03:16 linux-bd9o sshd[11921]: pam_mount(mount.c:65): Messages from underlying mount program:
Sep 20 16:03:16 linux-bd9o sshd[11921]: pam_mount(mount.c:69): NOTE: mount.crypt does not support utab (systems with no mtab or read-only mtab) yet. This means that you will temporarily need to call umount.crypt(8) rather than umount(8) to get crypto volumes unmounted.
Sep 20 16:03:16 linux-bd9o sshd[11921]: pam_mount(mount.c:69): /usr/sbin/mount.crypt: dmcrypt cipher ignored for LUKS volumes
Sep 20 16:03:17 linux-bd9o sshd[11921]: pam_mount(mount.c:69): crypt_activate_by_passphrase: Operation not permitted
Sep 20 16:03:17 linux-bd9o sshd[11921]: pam_mount(pam_mount.c:521): mount of /home/test.img failed
```

The same error, `crypt_activate_by_passphrase: Operation not permitted`, shows up when I try to run

```
cd /home
mount test.img test
```

To clarify, I'd like to fix the error first, since I can probably at least follow the SSH recipe given by [this sister question](https://superuser.com/questions/204787/how-can-i-mount-an-encrypted-home-directory-upon-ssh-login-using-private-public-k), if not modifying `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. Not being able to mount via command line is annoying.

The key is in CBC. I re-encoded it using [these instructions](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=430593&aid=2997185&group_id=41452), but the behavior is the same – local login works, SSH or command line `mount` fails. (Oddly, the octal dump did change, perhaps there is random information to prevent table lookups in the key.)